# Read from file into pointer to struct

Tags: c, file, pointers

I need help with pointers in C.
I have to read from a file, and fill an array with pointers to struct rcftp_msg .
Since now I did the next things:

```
struct rcftp_msg {

    uint8_t version;        
    uint8_t flags;              
    uint16_t len;       
    uint8_t buffer[512];    
};

struct rcftp_msg *windows [10];

pfile = fopen(file,"r"); // Open the file

I have to read from the file into the buffer, but I don't know how to do it.
I tried the next:

for (i = 0; i <10; i++){

leng=fread (**windows[i]->buffer**,sizeof(uint8_t),512,pfile);

}
```

I think **windows[i]->buffer** is bad, cuz that don't work.

Sorry for my bad English :(

Comment: Have you allocated `windows`?

Comment: You have a few correct answers below, but when you implement them also use something like #define BUF_SIZE 10 instead of repeating the literal everywhere. Not that it functionally matters but it is a better practice for future maintainability.

Comment: Is the `buffer[512]` element the actual size, or is it the *maximal* size, , where the `len` field determines the actual size?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `rcftp_msg *windows [10];` is an array of pointers that you have not initialized, ie allocated memory for.

To allocate memory to on of the pointers,  you should use `malloc`.

Like so:

```
windows[i] = malloc(sizeof(rcftp_msg));
```

Do that for each pointer in your array.

Also use `free()` to free the memory again when you're done.

Answer (score 0):

a `struct rcftp_msg *` is a *pointer* to a `struct rcftp_msg`, not the real thing. Thus you also need to allocate memory for the real thing. The easiest would be to *not* use pointers:

```
struct rcftp_msg windows[10];
…
for (i = 0; i <10; i++){
    len = fread (&(windows[i].buffer), sizeof(uint8_t), RCFTP_BUFLEN, pfile);
}
```

Or allocate memory before using.

```
struct rcftp_msg *windows[10];
…
for (i = 0; i <10; i++){
    windows[i] = malloc(sizeof(uint8_t) * RCFTP_BUFLEN);
    leng = fread(windows[i]->buffer, sizeof(uint8_t), RCFTP_BUFLEN, pfile);
}
```

Also make sure that `512 >= sizeof(uint8_t) * RCFTP_BUFLEN)`.